# Replace italics within Excel file with HTML tags

Tags: python, excel, excel-2011, vba

is there a way to replace formatting such as italics with their tags, e.g. ? More in general, how do I search for a format:italic and replace with

```
<i>foundstring(^&)</i>?
```

Basically what I want is to have this:

blabla *bla* bla

replaced with this:

```
blabla <i>bla</i> bla
```

This is because I need to export the .xslx to .csv while 'preserving' the formatting. Is there a VBA script which works with MS Office 2011 for Mac? Or can it be don, say, with Python?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: this is the vba code I tried to no avail:

```
Sub Tag_Italic()

Dim oWS As Worksheet

Dim oRng As Range

Dim FirstUL

Set oWS = ActiveSheet

Application.FindFormat.Clear

Application.FindFormat.Font.Italic = True

Set oRng = oWS.Range("A1:A1000").Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _

xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)

If Not oRng Is Nothing Then

FirstUL = oRng.Row

Do

oRng.Font.Italic = False

oRng.Value2 = "" & oRng.Value2 & ""

Set oRng = oWS.Range("A" & CStr(oRng.Row + 1) & ":A1000").Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _

xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)

Loop While Not oRng Is Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Edit 2: Gary's Student's answer did the job!

Comment: *Is there a VBA script ...?* If you write one, there will be. Depending on the size of the file and number of lines you need to parse, while it could be done in VBA, python would probably be better (or, any other language you're familiar with, which is able to work with Win32Com to access the Excel object model/api). This appears to be a "give me all teh codez" question, though. Have you even tried anything on your own yet?

Comment: If you can expect that entire cells are formatted in italics, you can just check the format properties of the cell(s) and wrap the text with the appropriate tags. If only *some* words in each cell are italicized, then you have to do character-iteration...

Comment: @David Thanks for your answers. I tried (http://vbadud.blogspot.ru/2008/12/how-to-search-italic-text-range-using.html) this macro to no avail. I'll try with Python - I'm pretty new with that so it might take me a bit of time. Thanks for pointing me in a good direction!

Comment: Put your code in the question body, not in the comments :)

Comment: It's likely your getting down votes for lack of effort...

Comment: Thanks David, I'm looking into openpyxl and hopefully will write back when I've found something to write about. I think some people could be a bit less hard towards a newbie. Once I've tried something reasonably acceptable I'll post it here.

Comment: That or you can use win32com to work with Excel, too.

Comment: Thanks - people of the openpyxl's project wrote to me that 'something like this is technically possible but extremely clumsy so we have decided not to support it.'. I'll now have a look at win32com!

Comment: Through win32com you can access the entire Excel object model/api. Most Excel - specific modules in python are designed to be lightweight and purpose built (i.e., only to *read* data/text, etc).

Comment: Thanks - is it [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) ?

Comment: I'm not 100% but that looks like it's probably it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function TagMaker(r As Range) As String
   Dim outpt As String, v As String, C As String
   Dim i As Long, boo As Boolean
   Dim booNext As Boolean

   outpt = ""
   v = r.Text

   For i = 1 To Len(v)
      boo = r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic
      C = Mid(v, i, 1)
      If (i = 1) And boo Then
         outpt = "<i>"
      End If
      If i = Len(v) Then
         If boo Then
            outpt = outpt & C & "</i>"
            Exit For
         Else
            outpt = outpt & C
            Exit For
         End If
      End If


      booNext = r.Characters(i + 1, 1).Font.Italic
      If (boo And booNext) Or (Not boo And Not booNext) Then
         outpt = outpt & C
      End If
      If boo And Not booNext Then
         outpt = outpt & C & "</i>"
      End If
      If Not boo And booNext Then
         outpt = outpt & C & "<i>"
      End If
   Next i
TagMaker = outpt
End Function
```

Examples:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, CSV stricly removes all formatting.

CSV stands for comma seperated values and is generally used in importing/exporting database or taking backups. If you are converting an excel file to CSV, all formatting tags will be removed including , table borders, highlights or font color and their styles. The data is stored in plain text.

Comment: I think you missed the ponit of the question, which was essentially "How do I convert rich-text to plain text with markup". As such, this answer doesn't really address the OP's question.